# Node.js: telnet "Rock, Paper, Scissors" Program not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, telnet

So I am trying to create this Rock, Paper, Scissors program to run on a telnet server. Except It's not allowing me to enter the words "Rock","Paper", or "Scissors".

1. First CPUhand is showing up as undefined and is not setting to one of the options in my if statements.
2. Second whenever I enter a single character in the command prompt, It gives me my "Invalid, try again!" else statement and skips to the next line.

Is anyone able to figure out why my if statements for CPUhand are not working or why I can't enter more than a single character in command prompt?

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PwGd.png) [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZqq4.png)

```js
"use strict"; 
const 
  net = require('net'), 
  server = net.createServer(function(connection) { //create server
      
      let randomNum = randomNumber(1, 3);
      let CPUhand
      
      if(randomNum == 1){
          CPUhand == "Rock";
      } else if(randomNum == 2){
          CPUhand == "Paper";
      } else if(randomNum == 3){
          CPUhand == "Scissors";
      }
    
 connection.write("Enter: Rock, Paper, or Scissors!\r\n");
      
 connection.on('data', function(chunk) { //collect data from user
  
  let USERhand = chunk.toString();
  
  if(CPUhand === "Rock" && USERhand === "Scissors" || USERhand === "Rock" && CPUhand === "Scissors"){
   connection.write("Rock beats Scissors!\r\n");
  } 
  else if(CPUhand === "Paper" && USERhand === "Rock" || USERhand === "Paper" && CPUhand === "Rock"){
   connection.write("Paper beats Rock!\r\n");
  } 
  else if(CPUhand === "Scissors" && USERhand === "Paper" || USERhand === "Scissors" && CPUhand === "Paper"){
   connection.write("Scissors beats Paper!\r\n");
  }
        else if(CPUhand === USERhand){
            connection.write("Draw!\r\n");
        }
  else{
   connection.write("Invalid! Try Again! \r\n");
  }  
  
 });

}); server.listen(5432); //bind port

    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

Comment: `.on('data')` is triggered whenever the program receives any data, and when you type something it's usually one character at a time. You'll have to collect the data to a variable until it receives a newline character. The other problem is because you try to assign values with `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score -1):

1) Typo in block:

`if(randomNum == 1){
  CPUhand == "Rock";
} else ...`

Should be:

`if(randomNum == 1){
  CPUhand = "Rock";
} else ...`

2) In user input you have also line break symbol:

`let USERhand = chunk.toString();`

Replace with:

`let USERhand = chunk.toString().trim();`